# Mock function elixir

Tags: testing, elixir

I have a function like this

```
def foo_bar() do
  Enum.reduce_while(
    image_options,
    0,
    fn image_option, _foo ->
      case image_option["destination"] do
        "s3" ->

          case response = Upload.upload_on_s3(foo, bar) do
            {:ok, _} ->
              {:cont, {:ok, "ok"}}
            {:error, _} ->
              {:halt, response}
          end
        _ ->
          {:cont, {:ok, "todo"}}
      end
    end
  )

end
```

I want to test foo_bar in unit test. How can I mock `Upload.upload_on_s3(foo, bar)` function?

Comment: Try this one -> https://github.com/jjh42/mock if you want to create a mock object or read this one -> http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/10/mocks-and-explicit-contracts/ and act accordingly

Comment: I'd advise against using Mock. It does dark magic with global names, which means that you a) don't really know what's going on under the hood (bad), and b) can't run your tests as `async: true` anymore (quite bad). The answer below, injecting the dependency, is way nicer and doesn't have any of these drawbacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@trptcolin wrote perfectly valid answer, however accepting upload_module as param explicitly for me it's a bit of hack, because you intentionally impact the behaviour of the working app, by injecting the mock.

I always in situations like these do:

```
1. Create a config for such case
# config.exs 
config :my_app, :uploader,
  RealUploader

# test.exs
config :my_app, :uploader,
  MockUploader

2. Write a mock uploader
# mock only public functions

3. Use it as module attribute to don't change the function call.

@uploader Application.get_env(:my_app, :uploader)
# few lines below...

@uploader.upload_on_s3(foo, bar)
```

It's just a matter of style, but my suggestion is not to change the function signatures and their list of arguments, just because you want to mock the dependency. Another advantage of using config, is that you can list all your external dependencies by putting them in one place. It will more clear for newcomer in the project.

Comment: nice, but how can I handle the response of MockUploader? `@uploader.upload_on_s3` have to return `{:ok,_}` and even `{:error,_}`
thanks!

Comment: Yes, it would :) It's just a module with hardcoded values to return.

Comment: I have this mock `def upload_on_s3(foo \\ %{}, bar \\ %{}) do
    {:ok, %{}}
  end`
but this function returns always {:ok,%{}} 
I can create even `{:error,%{}}` but how can I match the error ?

Comment: Maybe you have wrong order of function clauses. If your upload_on_s3 matches everything, imagine the case when should be an error ;)

Comment: I have to create two mock function. the first returns {:ok} and the second {:error}, but with the same name. In my "main" code I call `@uploader.upload_on_s3(foo, bar)` Then how can I get {:error} ?

Comment: Run your tests with arguments, that will match the clause for `{:error}` eg. in your test for `foo_bar()` you pass `:error` as a `foo`, so `upload_on_s3(:error, _bar)` would return `{:error, _}` etc. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157558/discussion-between-monkeyuser-and-patnowak).

Comment: FWIW the reason I like to pass dependencies like this in general in lieu of global config is because it makes the design more open to change in real (production) scenarios. For example if you connected to multiple storage services through this top-level code, passing the dependency makes this easy. It’s typically more convenient to depend on globals, but less flexible.

Comment: Sure, but this case is quite specific, isn't it? ;) You have a function `upload_on_s3`, which means your provider is specified - it's AWS S3. I do agree for "polymorhphism" when we deal with general functions.

Comment: Yep, I tried to make minimal changes to the original to demo the concept :) - in real life I would've changed many more things about the example code.

Answer (score 4):

You could change `foo_bar` to accept a dependency. Below I'm showing a module with a default argument, but you could omit the default, or pass a function instead if you prefer:

```
def foo_bar(upload_module \\ Upload) do
  Enum.reduce_while(
    image_options,
    0,
    fn image_option, _foo ->
      case image_option["destination"] do
        "s3" ->

          case response = upload_module.upload_on_s3(foo, bar) do
            {:ok, _} ->
              {:cont, {:ok, "ok"}}
            {:error, _} ->
              {:halt, response}
          end
        _ ->
          {:cont, {:ok, "todo"}}
      end
    end
  )    
end
```

Then, in your unit test, you can pass your own fake version of the upload module to have the behavior you want. For example:

```
defmodule BadFakeUploader do
  def upload_on_s3(_foo, _bar) do
    {:error, "bad stuff"}
  end
end

defmodule TestFooBar do
  use ExUnit.Case

  test "does the expected thing" do
    assert whatever == SUT.foo_bar(BadFakeUploader)
  end
end
```

Comment: That's a great approach. Too many developers have OO blinders and can't see the concept past the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [MecksUnit](https://github.com/archan937/mecks_unit/#an-example) (a Hex package I wrote) because I'm against altering ("exposing") code for the sake of mocking.

Opposed to [Mock](https://github.com/jjh42/mock) it does support asynchronous testing (because mock modules are isolated) and defining mock modules is much more readable / elegant.

And though MecksUnit uses [`:meck`](https://github.com/eproxus/meck) (which is inevitable if you want to be as unobtrusive as possible), it tries to be "as economic as possible" by only mocking once for every module-function-arity combination.

An example taken from https://github.com/archan937/mecks_unit/blob/master/test/mecks_unit/bar_test.exs:

```
defmodule MecksUnit.BarTest do
  use ExUnit.Case, async: true
  use MecksUnit.Case

  defmock List do
    def wrap(:bar_test), do: ~w(MecksUnit Bar Test)
  end

  setup do
    {:ok, %{conn: "<conn>"}}
  end

  mocked_test "parallel compiling", %{conn: conn} do
    task =
      Task.async(fn ->
        assert "<conn>" = conn
        assert [:foo, :bar] == List.wrap([:foo, :bar])
        assert ~w(MecksUnit Bar Test) == List.wrap(:bar_test)
        assert called(List.wrap(:bar_test))
      end)

    Task.await(task)
  end
end
```